# Accessing Struts2 web application war deployed on websphere 8.5.5 is throwing Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found

Tags: web-applications, struts2, websphere

Struts2 web application's war file deployed on Websphere 8.5.5.13 is displaying below 404 error on accessing the application:

> "Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: {0}"

I am able run the same war file locally and access the application fine. Any thoughts on what could be wrong or any pointers to resolve the error? Also, please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Tried the following suggestion with no luck:
https://frightanic.com/software-development/solution-to-error-404-srve0190e-on-websphere-6-1/

Comment: You should probably provide a bit more information about how the application is installed. Is the Struts jar in WEB-INF/lib? What context root did you deploy the app too? What URL are you requesting? Did you check the WebSphere SystemOut/SystemErr logs?

Comment: @dbreaux I see "struts2-core-2.3.34", if that what you were referring to at WEB-INF/lib location. URI is "clp-war.war,WEB-INF/web.xml" and context root is "//". Yes, I checked Websphere SystemOut and SystemErr logs and don't see anything logged when accessing the application URL.